# Laravel 4: File Upload says success not showing in folder

Tags: file, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to get a simple image file to upload, then move it to a designated folder, and though I get no error messages, and everything says it works, it won't show up in any folder. The code in question is:

```
        $destination = public_path().'/auction_img/';
        $filename = $auction->id;

        if (Input::hasFile('image')) {
            $file = Input::file('image');
            try{
            $uploadSuccess = $file->move($destination, $filename.$file->getClientOriginalExtension());
            }catch(Exception $e){
                error_log('Exception: '.$e->getMessage());
            }
            if($uploadSuccess){
                error_log("YAY!");
            }
        }
```

I'm not getting an exception, and I am getting the "YAY" in the error_log. But it won't show up whatever I do. Any ideas? I also checked my php.ini and it has a max size of 20M but the file is only about .5MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's not going where you think it is going.

First of all

```
try{} catch() {}
```

Doesn't work on Laravel. You have to set a handler:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);
});
```

Then do a full log of your move to see if it is really going where you need it to:

```
$destination = public_path().'/auction_img/';
$filename = $auction->id;

if (Input::hasFile('image')) {

    $file = Input::file('image');

    $uploadSuccess = $file->move($destination, "$filename.".$file->getClientOriginalExtension());

    if($uploadSuccess) 
    {
        error_log("Destination: $destination");
        error_log("Filename: $filename");
        error_log("Extension: ".$file->getClientOriginalExtension());
        error_log("Original name: ".$file->getClientOriginalName());
        error_log("Real path: ".$file->getRealPath());
    }
    else
    {
        error_log("Error moving file: ".$file->getClientOriginalName());
    }
}
```

Also check if the original file is where it is supposed to be.

According to the comments, your move should be:

```
$uploadSuccess = $file->move($destination, "$filename.".$file->getClientOriginalExtension());
```

Check if `$destination` points to your public folder, it must look something like:

```
/var/www/site/public/auction_img/
```

Check if `public_path()` returns `/var/www/site/public/` and if it doesn't you can use this in place of it:

```
$destination = app()->make('path.public').'/auction_img/'
```

Comment: Real Path seems to be empty. P.S. file is not going where it's supposed to be.

Comment: `$file->getClientOriginalExtension()` does it return `.ext` or `ext` ?

Comment: just ext or since it's a png file just png

Comment: Then, you missed the `.` in `$filename.$file->getClientOriginalExtension()`, I think it should be `$filename. '.' .$file->getClientOriginalExtension()`.

Comment: Also, what `$file->move(...)` will return if destination folder has no write permission, if it returns false then it's ok but if it silemtly fails then you should check for permission, didn't try file upload in `Laravel-4`.

Comment: Can you answer my second question about return value, when target folder has no write permission [`Antonio Carlos Ribeiro`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/457437/samuraisoulification) ?

Comment: It looks like I have write permission. Also I tried adding the extra "." but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: I'm not sure it will fail silently or not, but a fail to write will appear in the apache logs.

Comment: Can you check, what `echo $destination . $filename. '.' .$file->getClientOriginalExtension();` outputs ?

Comment: I get /auction_img/19.png

Comment: Is `base_path()` not necessary for full `url/absolute` in destination ? Or just relative path is enough ?

Comment: Antonio, That's why I was trying the try catch block. But that turned out to be fruitless.

Comment: Odd. Your code works fine for me: http://puu.sh/4YNfK.png. File written `public/auction_img/1.txt`;

Comment: I think, problem is somewhere else, you should post more code.

Comment: Well, I did change some stuff so I wouldn't have public anymore. Could this be the issue? I moved all my public stuff down a level and changed the index.php to reflect it.

Comment: Hang on I got it. If I have my $destination as just "auction_img" it works.

Comment: It could be because you've changed `public path`.

Comment: I re-added it in, it seems that the issue was the extra "/" in $destination = public_path().'/auction_img/'; once removed to look like $destination = public_path().'auction_img/'; it worked.

Comment: Your $destination is wrong. Mine is [2013-10-25 00:42:43] log.ERROR: Destination: /tank/dev.acr/public/auction_img/. Buy you said before 'I get /auction_img/19.png';

Comment: Yes, That's what I was getting before. But when I remove the front "/" it works, now I get auction_img/19.png

Comment: If you echo `public_path()`, you may get something unexpected because you said you've changed it.

Comment: Echoing public_path gives me nothing, it's blank. I think because I moved public up a directory so I wouldn't have the /public/ in my url's

Comment: That's the problem, you should have mentioned it earlier, BTW, all we did here is `debugging` which you could have done by yourself, anyway, glad to know that, your problem is solved :-)

Comment: Yeah, knowing works on your machines led me to the answer. Thanks sooo much guys. If one of you wants to make a new answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: Also, try to over ride the function `public_path()` because you've changed it, otherwise you may fall in more trouble in future.

Comment: Antonio gave an answer, let him edit it and go ahead, I'm happy, anyway.

Comment: You can use `app()->make('path.public').'/auction_img/'` instead of public_path() if you really can't use it anymore.

Comment: Please edit the answer so it'll be helpful for future reference, add the comment in your answer @AntonioCarlosRibeiro.

Comment: Just made the necessary changes to cover all we've seen here. If I missed something, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

$uploadSuccess in Laravel 4.0 at least, is not a boolean. It returns the file object after it has been moved (it returns $file, so it can be chained). This object cannot reliably be cast to a boolean (Symfony is raising an exception for me if I try to use it in an if-statement like you have).

If the file fails to be moved, then an exception will be raised. If an exception is raised, then you know the file has not been moved and remains where it is. As such, that leaves $file as a valid Symfony file object, and so your processing will continue with the file where it first landed.

So whether the file successfully moves or not, your "YAY!" is always in the execution path. You catch the exception if the move fails, log it, then fail to take any further action on the exception.